# How i can fix KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone inform me how to fix this crash coming in my application. I am unable to find why this crash is coming. I am not getting any clue. I search my project to find "objectIsKindOfClass" but i had not used this method.

[image]

Comment: Is this happening repeatedly or as a one off in the wild? If it's repeatedly run it through the debugger in XCode and follow the call chain until it dies.

Comment: i am getting crash list using crashlytic and this bug has occurred for more than 150 times

Comment: If it's only occurring in the wild it could be that the device is low on memory, try simulating a memory warning in the Simulator and see if it causes the same issue.

Comment: hmm good idea. let me check

Comment: Also check to make sure if you've got any dynamic loops they're not potentially running out of range, or if you're not using ARC you've not potentially released an object or set the retain count to 0 before calling it. It's probably going to be tricky to find if you can't replicate it.

Comment: yes, i check memory warning it is not giving any exception and i am also unable to replicate this bug.

Comment: @Developer did you make any progress on debugging this?

Comment: What do your other threads look like? What third party libraries are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In order to find this you need to enable NSZombie objects. Press Option + Command + R and

select the "Diagnostics" tab. Finally, click "Enable Zombie Objects".

Comment: i canot test it  using zombie because this is not happening for me. I am getting crash list from third party library.